# Input field caret position not getting set correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, caret

I have this directive down below for a `<input type="text>` field

```
myApp.directive('onlyDecimal', function () 
{
    return {
      require: '?ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) 
      {
            if(!ngModelCtrl) 
            {
                return; 
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function(val) 
            {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) 
                {
                    var val = "";
                }

                var clean = "";

                if(val !== null)
                {
                    clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "");
                }

                var start   = element[0].selectionStart;
                var end     = element[0].selectionEnd + clean.length - val.length;

                var negativeCheck   = clean.split("-");
                var decimalCheck    = clean.split(".");

                if(!angular.isUndefined(negativeCheck[1])) 
                {
                    negativeCheck[1] = negativeCheck[1].slice(0, negativeCheck[1].length);
                    clean = negativeCheck[0] + '-' + negativeCheck[1];

                    if(negativeCheck[0].length > 0) 
                    {
                        clean = negativeCheck[0];
                    }
                }

                if(!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) 
                {
                    decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0,2);
                    clean           = decimalCheck[0] + "." + decimalCheck[1];
                }

                if (val !== clean) 
                {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }

                element[0].setSelectionRange(start, end);

                return clean;
            });

            element.bind("keypress", function(event) 
            {
                if(event.keyCode === 32) 
                {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            var decimalCount = 2;
            var decimalPoint = ".";

            ngModelCtrl.$render = function() 
            {
                if (ngModelCtrl.$modelValue != null && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue >= 0) 
                {
                    if (typeof decimalCount === "number") 
                    {
                        element.val(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.toFixed(decimalCount).toString().replace(".", ","));
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        element.val(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.toString().replace(".", ","));
                    }
                }
            }

            element.on("change", function(e) 
            {
                var floatValue = parseFloat(element.val().replace(",", "."));

                if (!isNaN(floatValue) && typeof decimalCount === "number") 
                {
                    if (decimalCount === 0) 
                    {
                        element.val(parseInt(floatValue));
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        var strValue = floatValue.toFixed(decimalCount);
                        element.val(strValue.replace(".", decimalPoint));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

The purpose of this directive is to only allow numbers and 1 decimal in the field.

Let's say I have a value of `50.00` I then set the caret before the value which would be position 0 and I enter an invalid value of the key `b`. I set a console.log before I set the selection range and I get these values:

```
START: 0 END: 1
START: 0 END: 0
```

It runs twice and it seems to still move the caret to the next position.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues in your code that are causing problematic behavior:

1. In `ngModelCtrl.$render`, you are checking the type of `decimalCount` to determine if the `$modelValue` is a number or a string.  As soon as you start typing, `ngModelCtrl.$modelValue` becomes a string, but your logic still attempts to call `.toFixed()` on it, causing render to throw an exception, and preventing `setSelectionRange` from being called by the parser.
2. Your logic that is swapping commas for decimals is not being used in your formatter.  A value with a comma will come in, and the regex creating `clean` will remove it because it is expecting a decimal.  Once you fix that, you will have to also fix the comparison between `val` and `clean` at the end to swap decimals back to commas in `clean`.

**Overall, I would propose the following:**

1. Swap `if (typeof decimalCount === "number")` to `if (typeof ngModelCtrl.$modelValue === "number")`
2. Replace all commas with decimals before generating `clean`
3. Replace all decimals with commas in `clean` before comparing it back to the original `val`.